# How to remove a line from a text file?

Tags: php

I `write` string `data` into a text `file` inside a for loop :

```
$vokatra_res = fopen(RP_MAIN . "vokatra.res","a+");
$p = $vokatra->lireTout(array(), array("type_id")); // getting rows from database
for($l=0 ; $l<$p['cnt'] ; $l++) {
    $str = $p[$l]['produit_code'] . '|' . $p[$l]['type_id'] . '|' . $p[$l]['produit_lib'] . "\r\n";
    fwrite($vokatra_res, $str);
}
fclose($vokatra_res);
```

As a result there is a blank line at the end of the file. So how to remove this blank line before closing the file ?

Comment: If you don't have a blank line at the end of it, your data will be  all in one big clump as it's appended to the file. Show us an example of what the problem is. It's definitely the `. "\r\n"` doing that.

Comment: Perhaps the "\r\n" is creating the blank last line? I personally would insert an if inside the for loop, checking: `if ($l == ($p['cnt'] - 1)) { // print without "\r\n" because it is the last line }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid writing the extra newline by adding it to all lines except the last:

```
$newline = ($l < $p['cnt'] - 1) ? "\r\n" : ""; 

$str = $p[$l]['produit_code'] . '|' . $p[$l]['type_id'] . '|' . $p[$l]['produit_lib'] . $newline;
```

This code populates the `$newline` variable only if the loop is not processing the last line of data. The content of `$newline` (whether containing "\r\n" or not) is concatenated to the end of each string.

**Extra:**
The ternary operator can be difficult to understand; consider this code which produces the same result:

```
if ($l < $p['cnt'] - 1) {
    $newline = "\r\n";
else {
    $newline = "";
}
```

Comment: I know ternary operand  !

Comment: I expected that you would. However, I added the extra information for the benefit of future readers of this question who may be less skilful than yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ifyou do not want to check in every iteration, you can do like this:

```
$vokatra_res = fopen(RP_MAIN . "vokatra.res","a+");
$p = $vokatra->lireTout(array(), array("type_id")); // getting rows from database
for($l=0 ; $l<$p['cnt']-1 ; $l++) {
    $str = $p[$l]['produit_code'] . '|' . $p[$l]['type_id'] . '|' . $p[$l]['produit_lib'] . "\r\n";
    fwrite($vokatra_res, $str);
}
$str = $p[$l]['produit_code'] . '|' . $p[$l]['type_id'] . '|' . $p[$l]['produit_lib'];
fwrite($vokatra_res, $str);
fclose($vokatra_res);
```

You leave the last row outside the for loop. and you do not put the "\r\n" on it.

Otherwise:

```
$vokatra_res = fopen(RP_MAIN . "vokatra.res","a+");
$p = $vokatra->lireTout(array(), array("type_id")); // getting rows from database
for($l=0 ; $l<$p['cnt']; $l++) {
    $str = $p[$l]['produit_code'] . '|' . $p[$l]['type_id'] . '|' . $p[$l]['produit_lib'];
    if ($l < $p['cnt'] - 1) {
        $str .= '\r\n',
    }
    fwrite($vokatra_res, $str);
}
fclose($vokatra_res);
```

Is not very important how to check for last line during loop. Important is to avoid douple writing to file like:

```
for($l=0 ; $l<$p['cnt']; $l++) {
    $str = $p[$l]['produit_code'] . '|' . $p[$l]['type_id'] . '|' . $p[$l]['produit_lib'];
    fwrite($vokatra_res, $str);
    if ($l < $p['cnt'] - 1) {
        fwrite($vokatra_res, '\r\n');
    }
}
```